# Two pages, one jQuery script, error on one site

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now.
I have a developing environment, where I've added a lazy load script to a rather large file that was developed for the site by an external party. Everything works on all pages but one - on that site a lot of the functions suddenly aren't defined, and I am puzzled to say at the least.

One of the working pages is:
(Site removed due to local developing environment)

The page where I get the error in the console is:
(Site removed due to local developing environment)

The file is jquery.main.js
The only thing that has happened is that we've upgraded from 1.8.3 to 1.11.0 jquery - but since it works on all the other sites, I would be surprised if that was the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 `jquery.min` (v 1.10 and 1.11) files loaded in your page, remove the oldest.
One more tip, load your scripts in the bottom of the page to avoid headcaches.

**Update:**
Here are your jquery files:

In the top: 
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="(Site removed due to local developing environment)/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

In the bottom:
  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Turns out a Magento infinite scroll plugin was doing this :) Thanks a lot!